# Constructing a piecewise probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here I'm trying to construct a probability density function in the form $$f(t) = \begin{cases}
at, & t \in [0, 5) \\
b\sqrt{t}, & t \in [5, 20]\text{.}
\end{cases}$$
Of course, $$\int\limits_{0}^{20}f(t) = 1 \implies 12.5a + 52.17491948b = 1\text{.}$$
Since $f > 0$ in $[0, 20]$, I have to figure out what values $a$ and $b$ to choose so that $f > 0$. For this to work, I see that $a > 0$ and $b > 0$.

Then I have
$$a > 0 \implies \dfrac{1-52.17491948b}{12.5} > 0 \implies b < 0.019$$
approximately, and 
$$b > 0 \implies \dfrac{1-12.5a}{52.17491948} > 0 \implies a < 0.08\text{.}$$
It thus follows that $a + b < 0.099$ish, so I thought if I took $a + b = 0.09$ that I would get valid values for $a$ and $b$.

I have two equations:
$$\begin{align}
&12.5a + 52.17491948b = 1 \\
&a + b = 0.09 \implies 12.5a + 12.5b = 0.09(12.5) = 1.125\text{.}
\end{align}$$
It thus follows that $39.67491948b = -0.125$, which gives a negative $b$.

What am I doing wrong here?

**In short**: I'm wondering if given a value for $a + b$ that I can create a valid probability density function.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with the line $a + b = 0.09 \implies 12.5a + 12.5b$.

Comment: @JessicaK - Multiply all terms by $12.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $a$ and $b$ from the equations:

- $ra+sb=1$
- $a+b=c$

Here $r$ and $s$ are allready known to you and $c$ denotes a fixed number.

This comes to finding (linear) expressions for $a$ and $b$ in $c$.

Then check for wich $c$ the solution $\langle a,b\rangle$ satisfies $a\geq0\wedge b\geq0$.

For each of them the corresponding $f(t)$ is a PDF.